# Date conversion jsp

Tags: java, sql, jsp, data-conversion

I have jsp code that get date from the user (using html form) and I try to use the date in preparedStatament (sql).
the user enter date in format dd/mm/yyyy and i try to convert it into sql date yyyy-mm-dd...

this is the input type in the htl form:

```
<td><input type=date name="fdate"/></td>
<td><input type=date name="tdate"/></td>
```

this is the source code of dates.jsp (that run the sql):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
String fDateStr = request.getParameter("fdate");
String tDateStr = request.getParameter("tdate");
Date fdate = format.parse(fDateStr);
Date tdate = format.parse(tDateStr);

PreparedStatement prSelect = con.prepareStatement("select show_id,date,artist, name from shows where date between ? and ?");
prSelect.setDate(1, fdate);
prSelect.setDate(2, tdate);
```

This is the error that i get from `setDate` line:

```
"The method setDate(int, java.sql.Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, java.util.Date)"
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: some databases wouldn't allow you to create a column called "date"... what DBMS are you using?

Comment: it's ok, i have  a column named "date". this is hyperion sql (jboss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");` should be like

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Try to use Locale for safety

Again `Date fdate = format.parse(fDateStr);` gives you java.util.Date you need to convert it o java.sql.Date to set it to PreparedStatement like this

```
public static Date convertUtilDateToSqlDate(java.util.Date date){
        if(date != null) {
            Date sqlDate = new Date(date.getTime());
            return sqlDate;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then

```
prSelect.setDate(1, convertUtilDateToSqlDate(fdte));
prSelect.setDate(2, convertUtilDateToSqlDate(tdate));
```

Comment: I changed it, but I still got:
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The method setDate(int, java.sql.Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable 
  for the arguments (int, java.util.Date)
 - The method setDate(int, java.sql.Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable 
  for the arguments (int, java.util.Date)
on the line of "prSelect.setDate(1, fdate)"

Comment: check the full answer

Comment: I done it, but now I get:
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/01/2013"

Comment: that is because you have specified simpledateformat to parse this `yyyy-MM-dd` type of String and your input is 01/01/2013(dd/MM/yyyy) type change it in the simpledateformat argument

Comment: ok, I done what you said. now i understand, that the behavior in chrome and when i run it from eclipse explorer is different.
when I use yyyy-MM-dd it works from chrome
when I use dd/MM/yyyy it works in eclipse explorer
how can I do it generic?

Answer (score 1):

You must use `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`

Try this

```
prSelect.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(fDateStr));
prSelect.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(tDateStr));
```